# not able to power up usb port of RX111 controller

Tags: c, embedded

I have used LCD port of this RX111 and its working but I am not able to powerup the usb port of RX111.
please kindly suggest me a solution...I have put the main code of it

```
  void main(void)
  {
      R_MAIN_UserInit();
      /* Start user code. Do not edit comment generated here */
      Clear_Display();
      DisplayCenter(0, (uint8_t *)"USB Project");

      /* Start toggling the LEDs */
      R_CMT1_Start();

      /* Configure a switch press callback function */
      SetSwitchPressCallback(cb_switch_press);
      while (1)
      {
          if( R_usb_cstd_Scheduler() == USB_FLGSET )
          {
              R_usb_hstd_HcdTask();       /* HCD Task */
              R_usb_hstd_MgrTask();       /* MGR Task */
              usb_hmsc_Task();            /* HMSC Task */
              usb_hmsc_StrgDriveTask();   /* HSTRG Task */
              usb_hmsc_SampleAplTask();   /* HMSC Sample Task  */
          }
      }
  }   /* eof main() */
```

Comment: This should be forum "RenesasRulz". https://renesasrulz.com/

Comment: i reffered there but there is no information about powering up USB port..is there any other solution...

Comment: Presumably by setting `USB0_VBUSEN` but I would imagine that would be done in your HMSC class driver.  Are you using this:  https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/products/mpumcu/apn/rx/002/r01an0513ej0232_usb.pdf?  Does the sample application work?  Does your board actually support USB OTG?  If it an off-the-shelf board or a custom board? Do you know the hardware to be working?

Comment: It supports usb otg ...i tried one sample code...it doesn't have any error ...but i am not able to supply power to the usb port and do you have any idea on how to read and write data into a text file....